# Many NSOperationQueues = Many Threads?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsoperationqueue

I'm wondering would there be many threads if I have one NSOperationQueue in each of my View Controllers, that is, I have many NSOperationQueues in my app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Every `NSOperationQueue`, when running, its execution of the current `NSOperation` is on a separate thread.

If you've called `-setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:` passing in `1`, then you're guaranteed to only have one `NSOperation` running in the queue at any given time. (i.e. a serial queue.)

Otherwise, your `NSOperationQueue` could have as many as `NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount` threads running at any given time.

Comment: There's not a strict one-to-one relationship between the number of queues, their concurrent operation counts and system thread usage. NSOperationQueue is built on top of GCD (as of 10.6 and on iOS) and as such, will have its thread usage limited as determined by the system.

Comment: @AshleyClark I saw this on the NSOperationQueue Class Reference Documentation: Note: In iOS, operation queues do not use Grand Central Dispatch to execute operations. They create separate threads for non-concurrent operations and launch concurrent operations from the current thread. For a discussion of the difference between concurrent and non-concurrent operations and how they are executed, see NSOperation Class Reference.

Comment: Remember, GCD wasn't available on iOS until 4.0 while NSOperationQueue was available in 2.0. Just because it wasn't built on top of GCD then doesn't mean it isn't now. In any case, it's easily verified, set a breakpoint in an NSOperation's -main method and see what the backtrace looks like. If it contains "dispatch_*" functions, that's GCD.